# TeamCity CI server create project from the local folder

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, local

I'm the only developer in a team and will be working on a private project that doesn't need to be placed on the Github or somewhere else online. My entire project will be located in one of my local machine folders. Is this possible to create a project in TeamCity that points to my local folder? I'm using TC version 10. When I navigate to Create Project i only see **Manually**, **Github**, **URL Repository** and **BitBucket Cloud Repository**. Logically thinking I went to set up the project **Manually**, but there is a field **Project ID** which seems like require some sort of URL. Just curious if this ever possible with Team City? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Choose `git` as a type of repository and in mandatory field `Fetch URL` specify local path: `/path/to/repository`.
Click `Test connection` to make sure Teamcity is able to fetch data.

You won't be able to configure triggers against this repository, it is still open issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-12162

See screenshot [image: here].

Comment: I couldn't find a place in TC where I can give my local folder path to the git.

Comment: It is field called 'fetch url', same as you would use remote repository, but specify absolute path in Linux format.

Comment: Let me know, if you have got it I will post screen shot

Comment: Can you please provide step by step follow? I can't really find it.

Comment: So I go to Create Project -> Manually -> I can't see the field "fetch url". If I go to Create Project -> pointing to repository URL -> I can't see the field "fetch url". If I go to Create Project -> pointing to Github Enterprise repository ->  I can't see the field "fetch url". If I go to the Create Project -> pointing to BitBucket Cloud repository ->  I can't see the field "fetch url". May be we are talking about different places? Not sure

Comment: You need to choose git type of repository, since you use git as version control. Can you see fetch url there? I have tested it myself, pretty sure it will work. If not I will post screenshot, let me know.

Comment: Post a screenshot please if this possible. Thansk

Comment: Thanks! I was able to locate necessary place to create a project locally. Accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

with TC 2017.2.2 from URL Repository you can just give the path

```
file:///home/user/dirOfProject
```